# E: The package needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: apt, update-manager, thunderbird

I keep getting this error message when I try to use the update manager:

```
E: The package thunderbird needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

This error has slowed my computer down and does not allow me to use the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: @blunderboy: No, it's a different problem.

Answer (score 9):

The commands that resolve the above problem are:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

After that just run the Update Manager, and you should be all ready to go.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely since you removed the repository of the sources.list or the package in the cache is corrupted. You need to update your list and try to reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall install thunderbird
```

If you still have problems, check that you have in your sources.list a repository that has the same version of thunderbird that you installed.