# can't sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, update-manager

I tried to reinstall pip but there seems to be a problem with the location of some files related to the update manager.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
[sudo] password for benoit: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package update-manager needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

And then I get the following from an attempt to update the package update manager.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
    Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
    Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu xenial InRelease [17,5 kB]            
    Hit:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                          
    Hit:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                 
    Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                               
    Ign:6 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 InRelease                           
    Hit:7 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release  
    Ign:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease            
    Ign:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease
    Ign:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable InRelease
    Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu xenial InRelease
    Hit:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
    Hit:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release
    Hit:15 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable Release
    Fetched 17,5 kB in 0s (29,9 kB/s)                 
    Reading package lists... Done
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:24 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:24 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:24 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:24 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
    W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:24 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:24 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
    W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3BDAAC08614C4B38
    W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
    N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:24 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:24 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:24 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:24 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
    W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:24 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:24 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
```

I then tried to regenerate the source.list file, which didn't seem to solve the problem. Here's my source.list file as it is now.

[source.list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtfLP.png)

I don't quite see where I should investigate next. Could someone help?

Comment: The things you are showing us all appear to be warnings - what are the actual errors?

Comment: I thought this could be an indication of something problematic. I edited my post to provide more background to my issue.  In short, I need to reinstall my update manager but I don't quite see where to investigate.

Comment: Well I suggest you clear the errors (by removing repositories from your main `/etc/apt/sources.list` file that are also specified in files inside the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory - the `W:` messages tell you which those are) and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/147178/ethe-package-needs-to-be-reinstalled-but-i-cant-find-an-archive-for-it

Comment: @steeldriver - I have. I regenerate the source.list main file and have edit the repository you mentioned. This is what I get as output: `$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu xenial InRelease [17,5 kB]
Hit:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Ign:4 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 InRelease      
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease`

Comment: `Hit:6 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease            
Hit:7 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release        
Ign:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable InRelease
Hit:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable Release
Fetched 17,5 kB in 0s (24,0 kB/s)                  
Reading package lists... Done`

Comment: `W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3BDAAC08614C4B38
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

Comment: @luv.preet - Thanks for pointing out. I had already read this tread. I tried uninstalling with `sudo apt-get --purge remove update-manager` and other variants, but I get the exact same output, that archive files are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the `update-manager` package manually.

1. Download the package using on of the links from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/all/update-manager/download). You can choose any one, but it would be preferable to use the one for your country.
2. Install by running `dpkg -i /file/you/downloaded`

If there are any errors, could you please post them in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. There still seems to be some corrupted files elsewhere. I also very recently updated python and am wondering if this is where I might have messed up. Here is what I get out of the install you suggested. I seem to have to paste this over a few comments, as their are limited in size.

Comment: `$ sudo dpkg -i ./update-manager_16.04.6_all.deb 
(Reading database ... 420703 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../update-manager_16.04.6_all.deb ...
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 4
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /usr/bin/py3clean on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 4`

Comment: `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /usr/bin/py3clean on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
dpkg: error processing archive ./update-manager_16.04.6_all.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 4
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /usr/bin/py3compile on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`

Comment: `dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ./update-manager_16.04.6_all.deb`

Comment: Could you Post the first 4 lines of `/usr/bin/py3clean`.

Comment: Just run `cat /usr/bin/py3clean | head -4`

Comment: In case you are wondering, that code reads the file, and outputs the first 4 lines

Comment: nothing comes out even if I waited very long. It's as if the process is stuck in a loop. I have to close my terminal.

Comment: What about opening the file in a text editor