# E: The package needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it [ libpolkit-gobject-1-0]

Tags: xubuntu

whatever sudo `apt-get install` i got this error my server running smoothly but suddenly i got this error

here i try `sudo apt-get install -f`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libpolkit-gobject-1-0 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

this is the error i got  i have no idea what is this but i want to fix this issues so anybody know why its happen and how to fix it?

i refer this question

[E: The package needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147178/e-the-package-needs-to-be-reinstalled-but-i-cant-find-an-archive-for-it)

[Apt/Synaptic needs to reinstall package but can't find the archive for it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88371/apt-synaptic-needs-to-reinstall-package-but-cant-find-the-archive-for-it)

Comment: You didn't say what version you are running. The package is available if using the correct version (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpolkit-gobject-1-0); if using an unsupported or development version of Ubuntu your question is off-topic on this site (*is that why you didn't mention release of Ubuntu? if using Ubuntu at all.  It's a package used by Mint a lot more than Ubuntu!*)

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libpolkit-gobject-1-0` to the question and specify your Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo dpkg –-remove –-force-remove-reinstreq <package_name>`

`<package_name>` should be replaced with the name of the package you want to remove.

Comment: Can you explain how work that command (explanation of options for example) ? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1190266/edit) your answer.

Comment: Try ordinary `--force` first, or try troubleshooting the problem. `--force-remove-reinstreq` is the nuclear option: It will cause apt to forget that the package is installed, but it won't remove any of the files. You must cleanup all the fallout manually.