# E: The package mongodb-org-server needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to install mongodb compass. When I am trying to install I am getting

```
Preparing to unpack mongodb-compass_1.39.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-compass (1.39.0) over (1.39.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb-compass:
 mongodb-compass depends on libgconf-2-4 | libgconf2-4; however:
  Package libgconf-2-4 is not installed.
  Package libgconf2-4 is not installed.
 mongodb-compass depends on libgconf-2-4; however:
  Package libgconf-2-4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mongodb-compass (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-compass
```

After that I tried to install libgconf-2-4 using command

```
sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4
```

But getting error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: The package mongodb-org-server needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I tried using below command but none is working
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with i5 processor 16GB ram.

Comment: After a lot of research I tried command 
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mongodb-org-server and it worked. Thanks to post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075622/e-the-package-needs-to-be-reinstalled-but-i-cant-find-an-archive-for-it-lib

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes that post helped. Thanks

Comment: that was an autogenerated comment when voting to close ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: The package needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it \[ libpolkit-gobject-1-0\]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075622/e-the-package-needs-to-be-reinstalled-but-i-cant-find-an-archive-for-it-lib)